# Special national characters won't .split() in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, codec

I have trouble in Python,  when reading special national characters from a text file.

```
with open("../Data/DKsnak.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

str1 = content[0]
print "string:",str1

lst1 = str1.split()
print "list:",lst1
```

The output is a follow:

```
string: Udtræk fra observatør på årstal
list: ['Udtr\xc3\xa6k', 'fra', 'observat\xc3\xb8r', 'p\xc3\xa5', '\xc3\xa5rstal']
```

The first line is as expected, including special Danish charcters. But they don't survive being split into a string.
I have tried various tricks with codecs and unicode, but can't find the magic bullit.

Please can anyone suggest how I get these words into lists, so I can work with them as such.

Best regards
Martin

Running:
Python 2.7.5 (default, Feb 19 2014, 13:47:28) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)] on linux2

Comment: Try: `for item in lst1: print(item)`.

Comment: You don't have unicode, you have a *byte string*. Encoded bytes are not individual characters.

Comment: You are confusing string *representation* with string *values*; Python is giving you representations you can use to recreate the original values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. `python` simply stores its special characters like that. If you print out your text, you will still get the original strings:

```
s = 'Udtræk fra observatør på årstal'
s = s.split()

for i in s:
    print i

[OUTPUT]         #all fine
Udtræk
fra
observatør
på
årstal
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the for loop as mentioned before, if you want them on the same line:

```
for i in len(list1):

    string += list1[i] + ' '

print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

from https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('unicode.rst', encoding='utf-8')
```

so You get unicode and can split.